# SQL INSERT INTO SELECT WITH 2 WHERE CLAUSE AND PAIRED VALUES

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a service that will be importing excel files each time the service is used.  One excel file will be adding to the "Account" table  and another file will be adding to the "Transaction" table.  I have to run checks on these two files to try and match up 'Name' from 'Account' to 'TransactionName' from 'Transaction' (exact match, soundex, difference etc).  When they are matched the transaction file is updated to include the matching Account details (Thats whyt I have them in separate brackets below in the Transaction table.).

Each time a match is made the names and IDs are added to a table called 'Trained' so that next time, when other files are uploaded if they exist in those files and it says in the Trained table that they are a match then the Transaction table is updated automatically.  The 'AccountName' may appear several times in the Trained table as there may be several Transaction names that match it so in the Trained table the Primary Keys, because they have to be unique together is TransactionName and AccountNumber.

The 3 tables are:

```
Account(AccountNumber(PK), Name, Address)
Transaction(ID(PK), TransactionName, Address, (AccountNumber, Name, Address)))
Trained (TrainedID, ID, TransactionName(PK), Address, AccountNumber(PK), Name, Address, Status, 
Trained)
```

When a new file is uploaded and doing matches of exact and inserting to trained I dont want to duplicate items and Im getting an error.  How do I update this query to also include "If TransactionName and AccountNumber already appear as a pair in Trained then do not add again"?

```
insert into trained select Transaction.ID, Transaction.TransactionName, Transaction.Address,  
account.AccountNumber,  Status = 'Matched',  Trained='Exact'
from Transaction 
left join account on account.AccountName = Transactions.ResellerName
where Transactions.ResellerName = account.AccountName 
order by accountNumber
```

For example.  I upload an Account file and a Transaction file and my tables look like this:

Transaction-
[Account, Transactiona dn Trained table examples](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBV4n.png)

Next time a new Transaction file is uploaded, if it has TransactionName of '123Solutions' again and then tries to update the Trained table with its match again.  Bu the gtraied table already contains its match to AccountNumber80.  I get a Primary_Key error.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be so helpful.

Comment: Did you already try to add a second `left join` to your query in order to join the traines table to it? Would be roughly something like `left join trained tr on tr.TransactionName = Transaction.TransactionName and tr.AccountNumber = account.AccountNumber` and an extension of the where clause like `...and tr.TransactionName is NULL` ... this way you insert only the records which do not yet exist in the trained table...

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have added a image and another explaination. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
insert into trained 
select 
      Transaction.ID, 
      Transaction.TransactionName, 
      Transaction.Address,  
      account.AccountNumber,  
      Status = 'Matched',  
      Trained='Exact'
from Transaction 
left join account on account.AccountName = Transactions.ResellerName
where Transactions.ResellerName = account.AccountName  
and not exists(select * from traind where id = Trasnaction.id and accountNumber = account.accountNumber)
order by accountNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would suggest to replace your left join with an inner join since you use the where clause to filter exactly on the records matched by the join.
Furthermore you can add a left join to the trained table and then filter on all records which are not yet included in this table.
The query might look something like this:

```
insert into trained
select t.ID, t.TransactionName, t.Address,  
       a.AccountNumber,  Status = 'Matched',  Trained='Exact'
  from [Transaction] t
  inner join [account] a on a.AccountName = t.ResellerName
  left join [trained] tr on tr.TransactionName = t.TransactionName and tr.AccountNumber = a.AccountNumber
  where tr.TransactionName is null
order by accountNumber
```